# Run script when android off

Tags: shell, scripts

My alarm was ringing while my android device was off. I'm wondering if I can run a shell script while my android device is off.

Assume I have rooted android.

Comment: If a phone is shut down it can't execute anything. A few devices may have an autonomous subsystem for timer based actions, but those chips are usually not programmable in a general way, it is more executing pre-defined actions at certain times like creating an alarm sound or starting the phone.